# How to maintain unique error phrase and strings document for review every time in android

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to maintain a single document for all error codes and strings.And i need this document keep on updating when any error code or string is changed in my android application.Is there any better way to maintain a document like this for android applications.I want to link this error code(int) with string in strings.xml in resource file.Please help me guys.

Thanks
AnkiReddy

Answer (score 1):

The strings.xml docs is your friends i guess ?

you declare a phrase like this

```
<string name="delete_store">Delete a store</string>
```

and use it like this

```
android:hint="@string/delete_store"
```

Then if you change your value in the file string.xml, the value change all over your app.

Comment: I will try to explain it give me some time

Comment: Do not hesitate to mark this as the solution if it help you.

Comment: Actually we need to maintain error code for every string in strings.xml.So my question is how to link these error code (int value declared in errorcode.java) with respective string in strings.xml.And need to generate xml with all errocode with respected message.